# BlockUI JS cursor stays in loading after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui

I use BlockUI plugin to show loading screens on my application.

I use this to show loading before page reloads, but my problem is the pointer stays in "loading" after page refresh.

Here is a Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4aeu1vvk/1/

The code is simple :

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
location.reload();
```

Is a Chrome behavior or other ?

Comment: I think this is due to css addition of cursor: wait applied by blockUI.. will have to validate that

Comment: Yes but I reload page and so the cursor must be reseted no ?

Comment: Yes it should. see if you add custom css with cursor: crosshair .. it will remain crosshair. either blockUi is not removing classes or element properly or css for overlay is there but element goes away and browser is still thinking that cursor is still over that element.